# Iterated function 'periodicity'

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, function-and-relation-composition

Note: $f^n$ denotes the iteration of composition, e.g. $f^3(x)=(f\circ f\circ f)(x)$

---

I've noticed that particular functions have a certain property where for some number $n$ the iterations of the function cycle through a set of values so that $f^{m+n}(x)=f^m(x)$ for all $m\in\mathbb{N}$. For example, if $f(x)=1-\frac{1}{x}$:
$$f^1(x)=1-\frac{1}{x}$$
$$f^2(x)=1-\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{x}}=\frac{1}{1-x}$$
$$f^3(x)=1-\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{x}}}=x$$
$$f^4(x)=1-\frac{1}{x}$$
So the cycle has a  period of $n=3$. Is there a name for this property, and where can I find more information? Also, are there any cases where the 'period' $n$ varies as a function of the iterate $m$?

---

**Edit:**

As others have pointed to in the comments, the property I am describing can be stated succinctly by $F^n(X)=X$* for some $n$, and can apply to functions as well as operators on functions.

Since this extends rather naturally to integer $n$, idempotence and involution would be examples with periods $1$ and $2$, respectively.

If matrix multiplication is used to represent the composition of functions, then the property in question applies to any $M$ such that $M^n=\pm I$ for some $n$. As Will Jagy pointed out, in the example $f(x)=1-\frac{1}{x}$, $M^3=-I$ is given by the Moebius transformation $f(x)=\frac{x-1}{x+0}$.

Given how incredibly general this property is and the number of things to which it applies there is absolutely no way that I am the first person to notice it. There has to be a book or a paper somewhere, right?

---

*In retrospect, this should have been apparent given that $f^{m+n}=f^m\implies f^n=f^0$

---

"Corollary"?

If $$\frac{d^nf(x)}{dx^n}=f(x)$$ for some $n\in\mathbb{Z},n\neq0$, then $$\frac{d^{mn}f(x)}{dx^{mn}}=f(x)$$ and $$\int^{m(n-1)}f(x)\ dx^{m(n-1)}=f(x)$$ for all $m\in\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: You can think of $f(x)$ as the position of a particle at time $n+1$ when the position at time $n$ is $x$. Then $f^{n}(x)=x$ says the $x$ is  a periodic point with $n$ as a period.

Comment: If, for a positive integer $k$, $f^k(x)=x$ for all $x$ in the domain of $f$, then $f$ is $I^{1/k}$, a [fractional iterate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function#Fractional_iterates_and_flows,_and_negative_iterates) of the identity function.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Now THAT's an interesting point. I hadn't considered $f^n(x)=f^0(x)$ to be a criterion for periodicity, but in retrospect it makes sense. In fact, this seems to work for all integer iterates, since $f^{-1}(x)=\frac{1}{1-x}$ and $f^{-2}(x)=1-\frac{1}{x}$. $f$ doesn't even need to be a function, since this could apply to any operator for which $f^0$ is defined.

Comment: I also asked a similar question years ago, not being aware of this thread https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3734475/why-is-it-called-f-1x

Answer (score 2):

writing your function as the Moebius transformation
$$ \frac{x-1}{x+0}  $$
we get the matrix
$$
M =
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
1 & -1 \\
1 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
$$
Note that $M^2 -M+I=0$ so $M^3 = -I$
You can do something similar with any
$$
M =
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{array}
\right)
$$
and
$$  \frac{ax+b}{cx+d} $$
such that $M^n = I$ for some $n.$ It is also allowed to have the elements of $M$  complex if you want.

Comment: Okay, I had to learn what a Moebius transformation was first, but this only seems to apply to the quotients of linear functions, whereas functions with the property $f^n(x)=I(x)$, for some $n$, may not always be linear. Also shouldn't it be $M^2-M+I=0$ and $M^3=-I$?