# How to find the periodicity of a cycle through iterative assignments?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic

First, I'm not a mathematician by trade so if the terminology I'm using can be made more precise, please don't hesitate to improve this post.

Now that that's out of the way, this question looks like a more specific form of [Iterated function 'periodicity'](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3058108/iterated-function-periodicity). Specifically, if I have some function of the form $f(x)=(ax+c) \space mod \space m$ for some $a$, $c$, and $m$, how would I go about finding how many iterated compositions of the function (ie $n$ in $f^n$ where $f^n$ denotes the iteration of composition, e.g. $f^3(x)=(f\circ f\circ f)(x)$) will be the same as $f(x)$? Even more specifically, how would I know if $n=m$ (especially if $m$ is not prime)?

Context: I'm trying to generate a sequence of numbers such that all integers within $[0, m)$ are used and would prefer the given sequence not be easily predictable (although this doesn't have to be cryptographically secure).

Comment: Greg Martin's answer definitely supercedes the following comment, which I will still offer as a **from scratch** approach.  Consider the sequence of expressions: $~(ax+b), ~a(ax+b) + b = a^2x + ab + b,$ $~a^3x + a^2b + ab + b, \cdots.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are called [linear congruential generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator), so you'd probably be able to find a lot of information using that term. You won't get every integer from $0$ to $m-1$ this way, but you can get most of them (if $m$ is a prime then you'll get all but one such integer, for example, except in the case where $a\equiv1\pmod m$ which is a horrible random-number generator).

For the general situation of having an iterated function and wanting to find its period length on a given initial value: a standard observation is that it suffices to find a positive integer $k$ such that the $k$th iterate equals the $2k$th iterate (for then the period will be a divisor of $k$). This observation, which I learned in the context of the "Pollard rho algorithm" for factoring integers, is a lot easier to do in practice than comparing the $k$th iterate against all of the 1st, 2nd, ..., $(k-1)$st iterates every time.