# Prove that we have an isomorphism from the group generated by $1/x$, $(x-1)/x$ to the symmetric group $S_3$

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, group-isomorphism

> Prove that the group generated by $1/x$, $(x-1)/x$ is isomorphic to the symmetric group $S_3$.

What I already did is generate the elements $f \circ g=x/(x-1)$, $g \circ f=1-x$, $f^2=x$, $f\circ g \circ f=1/(1-x)$. It seems to be reasonable to assign $\phi(1/x)=(12)$ and $\phi((x-1)/x)=(123)$ since $(1/x)^2=x$ and $((x-1)/x)^3=x$. And through this to assign to every function a permutation.

But how do I show that I cannot generate more elements with the two base functions $1/x$ and $(x-1)/x$?

Comment: Compose the six elements that you have generated already by $f$ and by $g$. If you find no new elements then you have proved that you have found everything.

Comment: A deeper approach: These are both Möbius transformations, which act on $\mathbb C\cup \{\infty\}.$ If two Möbius transformations agree at three points , they are equal. These two functions permute $\{0,1,\infty\}.$ So the group generated by them are defined by the permutations generated.

Comment: And if you don’t want to use $\infty$ in that last example, they also permute $\{2,1/2,-1\}.$

Comment: Speaking of Marius transformations, you may also see [Iterated function 'periodicity'](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3058108/721644).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call the group $G$. Show that

$$\begin{align}
\varphi:G&\to D_3,\\
(x-1)/x &\mapsto a,\\
1/x &\mapsto b,
\end{align}$$

defines an isomorphism between $G$ and the dihedral group

$$D_3\cong\langle a,b\mid a^3, b^2, bab=a^{-1}\rangle$$

of order six. (Doing this could entail showing $G$ satisfies the relations in the presentation, so that $|G|$ is bounded above by $|D_3|$,  since $D_3$ would then map onto $G$.)

Use the well-known fact that $D_3\cong S_3$.

Comment: This is a genious-level move. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you, and you're welcome, @Iwan5050.