# How can I find the order of a function defined on a symetric group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, permutation-cycles

I have the following question, but don't know how to start for finding order of a function defined on a symetric group.

**Question**:

Consider the symetric group $S_X$ on the set $ X = \mathbb{R} - \{0, 1\}$. Let $f$ be the function defined by the following rule

$f(x) = (x-1)/x$

for all $x \in X$. Show that $f \in S_X$, and find the order of $f$ and the inverse of $f$.

I feel like the order of $f$ should be infinity but I am not sure.

Comment: What happens if you expand and simplity $f(f(x))$, $f(f(f(x)))$, and so on?

Comment: $f(f(x)) = f^{-1}(x)$ so this implies $f(f(f(x))) = e$. Does this mean the order of $f = 3$? @ahulpke

Comment: Yes, if that is so, the order is 3.

Comment: See also [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4272869/prove-that-we-have-an-isomorphism-from-the-group-generated-by-1-x-x-1-x-t). The order of $f=(x-1)/x$ is $3$, and the order of $g=1/x$ is $2$, and they generate the symmetric group $S_3$.